# Orbits of unipotent groups over local fields are closed?

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups, group-actions

Let $H$ be a connected, unipotent linear algebraic group defined over a local field $k$.  Let $H \times_k X \rightarrow X$ be an action of $H$ on an irreducible, affine $k$-variety $X$ which is defined over $k$.  Then the orbits of the group action $H(\overline{k}) \times X(\overline{k}) \rightarrow X(\overline{k})$ are Zariski-closed in $X(\overline{k})$.

What about the orbits of the group action $H(k) \times X(k) \rightarrow X(k)$?  By the general theory of analytic manifolds, the orbits are locally closed subvarieties of $X(k)$.  Are these orbits always closed, as in the algebraically closed case?

Comment: Can you further explain how this relates to Kostant-Rosenlicht ([1961](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=130878), Thm 2); Birkes ([1971](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=296077), Thm 12.1); Borel ([1991](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1102012), Prop. 4.10)?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you are asking.  Those theorems just say that the orbits of $X(\overline{k})$ under a unipotent group are Zariski closed, right?

Comment: Just curious and unsure how algebraic closure enters, in these refs.

Comment: If $V \subseteq \mathbb A_k^n$ is an affine scheme of finite type over a field $k$, then $V(\overline{k})$ is an affine variety in the classical sense, i.e. the set of zeroes in $\mathbb A_k^n(\overline{k}) = \overline{k}^n$ of some set of polynomials.  In Borel and the other references, they are working with classical varieties.  So when they talk about a variety $V$, their $V$ is really our $V(\overline{k})$.

Comment: I see; thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: This answer is valid only in characteristic 0!

Yes. For a unipotent group $H$ the orbits of $H(k)$ in $X(k)$ coinside with the intersections of the form $H(\bar{k}).x \cap X(k)$, hence even Zarizki closed. In general, the orbits of $H(k)$ on sets of the form $H(\bar{k}).x \cap X(k)$ are classified by the first cohomology $H^1(k,H_x)$ for $H_x$ the stabilizer of $x$ in $H$. But Galois cohomology of unipotent groups vanish. This is a generalization of the fact that $H^1(k,\mathbb{G}_a) = \{1\}$ and in fact follows from this, since every unipotent group has a filtration with associated graded consist of several copies of $\mathbb{G}_a$, so by induction and some long exact sequences it follows.

Comment: Thank you.  Does the cohomology set $H^1(k,H_x)$ arise from looking at the exact sequence of pointed sets $1 \rightarrow H_x(\overline{k}) \rightarrow H(\overline{k}) \rightarrow H(\overline{k}).x \rightarrow 1$?

Comment: more or less, but you need to be careful here. The statement that the orbits of $H(k)$ are classified by the cohomology is stringer than the exactness of the corresponding long sequence of cohomology, as a sequence of pointed sets. The action of $H(k)$ on $(H(\bar{k}).x)(k)$ is important.

Comment: The method of proof in this answer is incorrect when ${\rm{char}}(k)=p>0$ since the scheme-theoretic stabilizer $H_x$ is merely a unipotent group scheme and not necessarily smooth nor connected nor (even if smooth and connected) $k$-split.  In particular, it has no reason to have a filtration with successive quotient $\mathbf{G}_a$, and over imperfect fields of characteristic $p$ (including local function fields) the degree-1 cohomology of a form of $\mathbf{G}_a$ can be nontrivial and even infinite.

Comment: true, this works only for characteristic 0. thanks.

Comment: It is still true in char. $p>0$ that the orbits of $H(k)$ are closed in $X(k)$ for the valuation topology. First, the algebraic orbit (scheme-theoretic image of the orbit map) is a closed subscheme $Z$ of $X$ by Rosenlicht, so you may replace $X$ by $Z\cong H/H_x$. The projection $H\to X$ is then an $H_x$-torsor, and the result follows from Theorem 1.2 in my paper with O. Gabber and P. Gille (Algebraic Geometry 5 (2014) 573–612). This works over any henselian valued field $k$ whose completion is a separable extension of $k$.

Comment: "every unipotent group has a filtration with associated graded consist of several copies of $\mathbb G_a$..." What about when the unipotent group is not connected?  In that case, it is not split

Comment: The connectivity is not a big deal. The map $(H/(H_x)^0)(k) \to (H/H_x)(k)$ is proper, so you can always reduce such a claim to the case where  the stabilizer is connected, I think.

Comment: Can you explain a little more?  Why is this map proper, and how can this be used to show that $H^1(H_x)$ is trivial from the fact that $H^1(H_x^{\circ})$ is trivial?

Comment: I hope im right here. The map $H/(H_x)^0 \to H/H_x$ is a Galois cover with Galois group $H_x / (H_x)^0$. I might use characteristic 0 again here, my intuition is mostly p-adic, but I hope not :-) Anyway, the group $H_x / (H_x)^0$ is finite, and finite Galois cover is always proper. Given this, using the cohomological triviality of $(H_x)^0$ we get that the $k$-orbit in $H / (H_x)^0(k)$ is closed, so its image by the proper projection to $H / (H_x)(k)$ is closed as well. But this is exactly the $H(k)$ orbit (I use here the fact that taking $k$-points of a finite Galois cover gives proper map.)